# Gas Price Must Be Greater Than Or Equal To 0.1 GWEI in Metamask

Tags: private-blockchain, metamask, quorum

I have setup a private quorum network, connected the metamask with my quorum network and it is connecting but when am trying to do transaction getting an alert **Gas Price Must Be Greater Than Or Equal To 0.1 GWEI**. If am giving some gas price also the transaction gets failed with the error

> [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":1353645564715,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["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"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: rlp: input string too long for uint8, decoding into (types.Transaction)(types.txdata).V
>   (anonymous) @ popup.js:89481

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Quorum chain has its chainId set to the same as your networkId, or MetaMask will not encode the transaction correctly for your chain, per [EIP 155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155).

Comment: I'm completely failing to understand how this answer is related to the question. :/

Answer (score 0):

@Jazz In meta mask you can customize your gas price to zero even though it shows some warning message. I have followed the below link to customize the gas price in meta mask after this user can perform transactions easily. https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015488771-How-to-Adjust-Gas-Price-and-Gas-Limit-